# Image Recognition BlackBerry?

Tags: java, blackberry, image-processing, blackberry-jde, image-recognition

I'm trying to develop a sort of AR for **BlackBerry devices**. Trying to achieve the best compatibility for old devices, if it's possible I would like to make it for BlackBerry OS 5 / 6.
Due to lack of hardware performance, I'm not trying to show a real-time solution on screen. Right now I just want to recognize some symbol that the camera see, at the moment the symbol is recognized I want to capture a photo of the current view.

After that, I want to crop part of the captured photo and compare it with a imagery and determine if it matches some image.

I'm quite advanced on researching the alternatives, for the image comparing step, I know there are two common techniques **histogram and keypoints**. I'm almost decided to use histogram method, but I'm worried about the colors captured by the camera could be a little different from which ones I got in the database (due to light sources, colors, etc.)

Any ideas of which is the best method to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Thanks!